# Zend DB MySQL not insert in certain tables

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

We have the same code running on different MySQL databases, saying db1, db2...and etc. We insert records into table1 for every db, like db1.table1, db2.table2...etc.

The same piece of code written in Zend DB Adapter can insert every table1 in every database, except one. Compare the database schema and they are all created the same. Manually inserting the record to the table1 is successful in every table.

What could be the possible reasons? How to further troubleshoot?
The MySQL version is 5.0.0.7.

Comment: Could be lots of things (missing foreign keyed entry, missing column, etc.); it's hard to know without seeing the CREATE TABLE statements for the 2 databases.

Comment: Same schema for two different database.

Comment: Check the query log for both databases. The one that does not do insert always has "Init DB" before each "insert" and skip the table we would like to insert to; the other does not have "Init DB" and does not skip inserting to the table we want to insert to.